# Azure Mobile Apps android 3.3 login flow, eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, azure-mobile-services

I am attempting to update my android apps to use version 3.3 of the azure mobile apps sdk for android downloaded from here.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-android-client

To remove complication I created a new project based on microsoft's documentation here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-users

I placed the .jar file in the libs directory of my project.  When I attempt to run the project I get a unable to find explicit activity class error for the class .authentication.CustomTabsIntermidiateActivity.

I then have attempted to declare this activity in my manifest multiple different ways, but I still get this error.

I then downloaded the master file and attempted to import it into eclipse and set it as a library, but am getting the same error.  The missing value is present in the manifest of the master file.

How should I proceed?

my manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pleasework"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            </activity>

        <activity android:name=".authentication.RedirectUrlActivity" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https://myservice.azure-mobile.net/"
             android:host="easyauth.callback"/>
            </intent-filter>     
            </activity>

         <activity android:name="com.example.pleasework.com.microsoft.mobileservices.authentication.CustomTabsIntermediateActivity" android:exported="true">

            </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have tried this both with and without the final activity declaration and have also tried various permutations of 
com.microsoft.mobileservices.authentication.CustomTabsIntermediateActivity

No matter what values are in my manifest I still get  error

I realize that the suggested solution is to migrate to android studio, but I have a few apps using this flow and don't want to migrate everything now.

Comment: First, I don't know which version of Azure Mobile Android SDK you used before updated.

Comment: According to the [Version Information](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-android-client#version-information), if the previous version is 2.x, you need to first [migrate your existing Azure Mobile Service to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-migrating-from-mobile-services) and upgrade your existing backend of Azure Mobile Service to App Service (for example, [Node.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-node-backend-upgrading-from-mobile-services)).

Answer (score 0):

According to your `AndroidManifest.xml` content, per my experience, I think the issue was caused by the `.authentication.RedirectUrlActivity` activity class which is belong to the package `com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices`, not your defined package `com.example.pleasework`. So please you could not use the short class name at here.

Please try to replace the content below in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<activity android:name=".authentication.RedirectUrlActivity" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https://myservice.azure-mobile.net/"
             android:host="easyauth.callback"/>
            </intent-filter>     
            </activity>

         <activity android:name="com.example.pleasework.com.microsoft.mobileservices.authentication.CustomTabsIntermediateActivity" android:exported="true">
            </activity>
```

with the correct one.

```
<activity android:name="com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.authentication.RedirectUrlActivity">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
         <data android:scheme="{url_scheme_of_your_app}"
             android:host="easyauth.callback"/>
     </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```